# Define a reference of the member variable of a vector of a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

This code explains an example of what I want to do:

```
class Object
{
public:
    int data;

    Object() : data(0) {}
    Object(int data) : data(data) {}
};

int dataSum(vector<int>& dataReference)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dataReference.size(); i++)
    {
         sum += dataReference[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Object> myObject(5);
    int mySum = dataSum(myObject.data); // this line does not work

    return 0;
}
```

It's obvius that this can be done easier making dataSum a member function of Object, but this is not what I am asking. How can I just reference myObject.data? Or at least doing the same with a pointer if it cannot be done with a reference.

Edit: Some people have told me that the question is not clear.
What I want to do is reference every integer of `myObject[i].data` putting them in a `vector<int>` reference. 
Sorry also If I have put some grammatical error, English is not my native language.

Comment: Why are you attempting to pass `myObject.data`? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: I even can't imagine the original purpose of passing `int` to a function accepting `std::vector`.

Comment: To store references in a `std::vector` you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: @Ron It isn't passing an `int`.

Comment: Or simply pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, right you are. My bad. That's lack of sleep for you.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Your code doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Sorry if my code isn't enough to explain whay I want to do. I just pretend to sum all myObject.data integers, calling a function. But the function just have as a argument vector<int>&

Comment: If this was even possible, I wonder how would this property be called — orthovariance?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want this?

```
int dataSum(const vector<Object>& dataReference)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dataReference.size(); i++)
  {
    sum += dataReference[i].data;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  vector<Object> myObject{ 1,2,3,4 };
  int mySum = dataSum(myObject); // mySum will be 1+2+3+4 (=10) here.

  return 0;
}
```

or better:

```
int dataSum(const vector<Object>& dataReference)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (const auto & object : dataReference)
  {
    sum += object.data;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this code reference the entire myObject. I just want to reference the integers for myObject.data, because this function should work for example for another  vector<int>

Comment: @Rafael you cannot do this directly;if you have a vector of objects you cannot pass that vector to a function that wants a vector of ints. It's somewhat unclear.

Comment: So, if the function needs to remain untouched, the only way to do what I asked is creating a copy of every myObject.data in to a new vector<int> and passing it to the function?

Comment: @Rafael yes, but that would be inefficient. Maybe Arnav Borborah's answer is what you need

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

```
vector<Object> myObject(5) { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int mySum = std::accumulate(myObject.begin(), myObject.end(), 0, 
            [](int init, const Object& obj)
            {
                return init + obj.data;
            }); // mySum = 15
```

This removes the need for the function in the first place and achieves what you want with a simple function call!

If you wanted to do the same thing with a `std::vector<int>`, then you could just call the same function without a binary predicate.

Comment: The function dataSum is just an example. The function for what I want to use this is more complex. I just want to reference as a vector<int> the integers of every myObject[i].data Thanks for reply, but this is not what I asked. Sorry if if I have not been clear...

Comment: @Rafael If that is what you need, then you will have to implement some sort of template function that accepts a binary predicate and iterators and does the same thing.

Comment: You can look at the implementation of `std::accumulate` as an example (To which I linked to)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to pass `std::vector<Object>&` into a method whose signature requires `std::vector<int>&`. If you want to handle a vector of `Object` types then that's what you need to implement.  If you want to use the method you have defined for `dataSum` then you need to use it like this.

```
std::vector<int> numVec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Object obj;
int sum = obj.dataSum(numVec);
```